# Regex - Extracting File Paths

Tags: c#, regex

I need to be able to extract the full file path out of this string (without whatever is after the file extension):

```
$/FilePath/FilePath/KeepsGoing/Folder/Script.sql (CS: 123456)
```

A simple solution such as the following could would work for this case, however it is only limited to a file extension with 3 characters:

```
(\$.*\..{3})
```

However, I find problems with this when the file contains multiple dots:

```
$/FilePath/FilePath/File.Setup.Task.exe.config (CS: 123456)
```

I need to be able to capture the full file path (from $ to the end of whatever the file extension is, which can be any number of things). I need to be able to get this no matter how many dots are in the name of the file. In some cases there are spaces in the name of the file too, so I need to be able to incorporate that.

*Edit*: The ending `(CS....)` in this case is not standard. All kinds of stuff can follow the path so I cannot predict what will come after the path, but the path will *always* be first. Sometimes spaces do exist in the file name.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the ending predictable? Can't you just trim out `" (CS....)"`?

Comment: Will the file always end with something along the lines of ` (CS: ....)`? If so, you could grab everything up until that...

Comment: Use context [`Regex.Match(s, @"(\$/.*) \(CS: \d+\)").Groups[1].Value`](https://regex101.com/r/KM0fbv/2)

Comment: @BrootsWaymb ending is not very predictable. It just happens to be (CS....) in this case but sometimes there are other things as well, which all don't follow a standard format so they could really be anything.

Comment: @shindigwagon will the path contain spaces? - if not `path.Split().First();`

Comment: @fubo: "In some cases there are spaces in the name of the file too"

Comment: @shindigwagon - Is there any predictable character that signals the end of the path in some way? For example, `:` is an invalid windows path character (don't know about other OS). If you could have something such as `(=+& d #` after your file, it's going to be tricky to know if that is extraneous info, or part of the filename. If garbage is always coming in, you're going to keep getting garbage out.

Comment: There is no general solution. `A B.C D.E` is a valid filename. So is `A.(B).(C D)` The only illegal character I see in your strings is the `:`, but that part isn't fixed.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb I could have people start using a separator in these strings to make it easier for us to extract that name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`(\$.*\.[\w.-]+)`

But! it will not properly match files with space or special chars in the file extension. If you need to match files that might have special chars in the file extension you'll need to elaborate on the input (is it quoted? is it escaped?).

Comment: Works like a charm. Spaces are not a common occurrence, but they do happen from time to time. This seems like it works otherwise though. Thanks :)

Comment: If you could provide a larger dataset we can try to find a better solution